# Can't call method "try" without a package or object reference

Tags: perl, try-catch

I have a try catch block in perl

```
try {
    //statement 1
    //statement 2
};
catch Error with
{
    print "Error\n";
}
```

When I run the perl program I get the following error

> Can't Call method "try" without a package or object reference at...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl does not provide `try` or `catch` keywords.  To trap "exceptions" thrown by `die`, you can set a `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler or use [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).  Block form is preferred over string form, as parsing happens once at compile time.

```
eval {
    // statement 1
    // statement 2
}
if ($@) {
    warn "caught error: $@";
}
```

There are various modules that provide more traditional `try`-like functionality, such as [`Try::Tiny`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try%3a%3aTiny).

Comment: You missed the ; on the end of the eval { ... }; statement. For such reasons it's usually easier to use Try::Tiny

Answer (score 5):

You probably wanted one of the CPAN modules such as `Try::Tiny`:

```
use Try::Tiny;

try {
  # statement 1
  # statement 2
}
catch {
  print "Error\n";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to give [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try) a try. It is quite unique and provides all the features of a trycatch block like in other programming languages.

It supports exception variable assignment, exception class, clean-up with `finally` block, embedded try-catch blocks.

Full disclosure: I have developed [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try) when [TryCatch got broken](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=97089).